# State of the art on relativistic perihelia precession in Solar System (other than Mercury)

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, astronomy, solar-system, precession

The correct prediction of anomalous precession rate of Mercury perihelion is a classical test of General Relativity and one of its' big triumphs. How about other planets in the Solar System?

Perihelion shift per period  predicted by GR is

$$\frac{6\pi G M}{c^2 a (1-e^2)}$$

where $M$ is Solar mass, $a$ is semi-major axis, $e$ is eccentricity. $(1-e^2)\approx 1$ practically for all planets. Precession angle per century is often used, which requires further dividing by $T\sim a^{3/2}$. For planets like Venus and Earth the resulting $a^{5/2}$ in the denominator is within the same order of magnitude as for Mercury. Since for Mercury it is known with at least a 2-digit accuracy, what is the problem with testing GR on Venus and Earth as well?

As far as I understand, the problem comes from the fact that orbits of Venus and Earth have much lower eccentricity (0.007 and 0.02, respectively) than Mercury (0.2). This contributes to larger uncertainties in measuring the perihelion shift and this uncertainties make comparison to the GR prediction impossible. At least, it seems that this was so in the beginning of 20th century, and only Mercury has become a classical test of GR.

But measurement accuracy is constantly improving and here we come to my question. **What is the state of the art of testing GR prediction for perihelion shift with planets in Solar System other than Mercury?** Various sources online provide mutually contradicting estimates. As an example:

[Azimuthally symmetric theory of gravitation – I. On the perihelion precession of planetary orbits](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1365-2966.2009.16196.x) by G. G. Nyambuya (2009) in Table 1 provides uncertainties that make only rough comparison possible.

On the other hand, in [Relativistic Perihelion Precession of Orbits of Venus and the Earth](https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.0176) by Abhijit Biswas and Krishnan R. S. Mani (2008), the authors give much-much lower uncertainties in their Table 1. According to them, the agreement with GR is perfect, even unrealistic. Following their references I did not manage to find the source of these estimates.

I hope to find a more definite answer with the help of the community.

Comment: @Qmechanic The link was edited by another person, I hope it is fine this way. Regarding the resource recommendation tag: the primary goal of my question is to understand the current state of the problem, so I would appreciate an answer from an expert even without a reference.

Comment: Res. recom. can usually not be mixed with an actual physics q, so you have to choose.

Comment: Have you checked out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity#Perihelion_precession_of_Mercury? It lists data on Venus and Mars with a reference.

Comment: Another issue is that the motion of the centre of the Earth is more complicated than the orbit of the EMB (Earth-Moon barycentre). This makes determining the exact time & location of the Earth's perihelion (in distinction to that of the EMB) somewhat tricky.

Comment: @my2cts I have not seen this, thank you! I am a bit sceptic, though: the reference from Wikipedia leads to the second paper I gave a reference to, and their source is unclear. They claim that uncertainties for Venus, Earth and Mars are of order 0.0001 arcseconds/century. The same Wikipedia article says the uncertainty for total Mercury perihelion shift is 0.65 arcseconds/century, although the reference for this dates back to 1947. So I am a bit puzzled by the discrepancy in these uncertainties estimates.

Comment: @PM2Ring That's a nice point, I think we should be interested in perihelion of EMB for this sort of questions. Do you mean that it is easier to determine EMB perihelion location theoretically (this makes sense to me) or experimentally (this makes less sense naively)?

Comment: The 1947 is based on calculations from 1912 and the observations compiled by Le Verrier on the 1860's!

Comment: Theoretically. Our best ephemerides are the [JPL Development Ephemeris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_Propulsion_Laboratory_Development_Ephemeris) series, which are created by numerically integrating the motions of all major Solar System bodies, down to the 343 most massive asteroids (although they track many thousands of smaller asteroids & moonlets too). You can freely access the portion of DE 431 ranging from 9999 BC to 9999 AD via the Horizons interfaces.

Comment: (cont) However, as explained in the [docs](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?horizons_doc#longterm), "For example, while the center of Mars (499) is available over a few hundred years as defined by the solution for the motions of the moons Phobos and Deimos, the Mars system barycenter (4) is available over 9999 B.C. to A.D. 9999".

Comment: @my2cts OK, thanks for looking into this. 3 orders of magnitude improvement in accuracy over 150 years  certainly looks more plausible to me than over 60 years (but being far from astronomical measurements my feeling is based just on common sense).

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, this makes perfect sense. The problem then is that our measurements are for the center of the Earth but the calculations are best for the EMB.